# What is wrong with this Oracle query? ( ORA-00904: "DURUM": invalid identifier)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write an SQL query. If it works in Oracle SQL Developer, I will use it in TableAdapters query. This is the query; DURUM doesn't belong to any table but I will ad it as a field in the TableAdapter

Error is; ORA-00904: "DURUM": invalid identifier

```
SELECT IPYYB_BELGE.BELGEID,
       IPYYB_MUELLIF.MUELLIFID,
       IPYYB_MUELLIF.AD,
       IPYYB_MUELLIF.SOYAD,
       IPYYB_MUELLIF.TCKIMLIKNO,
       IPYYB_BELGE.SERINO,
       IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP.ACIKLAMA,
       IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI,
       IPYYB_BELGE.SONGUNCELLEMETARIHI,
       IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN.ACIKLAMA AS UNVANACIKLAMA,
       DURUM,
       CASE
         WHEN IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI >= 2012 THEN 'EDA'
         WHEN IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI < 2012 THEN 'GECE'
       END AS DURUM
FROM IPYYB_MUELLIF,
     IPYYB_BELGE,
     IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP,
     IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN
WHERE IPYYB_MUELLIF.MUELLIFID = IPYYB_BELGE.MUELLIFID
AND   IPYYB_BELGE.GRUPID = IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP.KOD
AND   IPYYB_MUELLIF.UNVAN = IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN.KOD (+)
```

The solution is

```
SELECT IPYYB_BELGE.BELGEID,
   IPYYB_MUELLIF.MUELLIFID,
   IPYYB_MUELLIF.AD,
   IPYYB_MUELLIF.SOYAD,
   IPYYB_MUELLIF.TCKIMLIKNO,
   IPYYB_BELGE.SERINO,
   IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP.ACIKLAMA,
   IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI,
   IPYYB_BELGE.SONGUNCELLEMETARIHI,
   IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN.ACIKLAMA AS UNVANACIKLAMA,

   (CASE
     WHEN IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI >= 2012 THEN 'EDA'
     WHEN IPYYB_BELGE.ALINMATARIHI < 2012 THEN 'GECE'
   END) DURUM
FROM IPYYB_MUELLIF,
     IPYYB_BELGE,
     IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP,
     IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN
WHERE IPYYB_MUELLIF.MUELLIFID = IPYYB_BELGE.MUELLIFID
AND   IPYYB_BELGE.GRUPID = IPYYB_PRM_BELGEGRUP.KOD
AND   IPYYB_MUELLIF.UNVAN = IPYYB_PRM_MUELLIFUNVAN.KOD (+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `"EDA"` should be a character constant, you need to use single quotes, not double quotes.

`"EDA"` is a column name, whereas `'EDA'` is a character literal

**Edit**

`DURUM` apears *before* your case statement. You cannot reference a column alias like that

Actually I think it's not needed because the CASE statement will return a column named DURUM.

Comment: I tried it now, gives the ORA-00904: "DURUM": invalid identifier error

Comment: how can I set DURUM so that I can return it in Select like other fields such as IPYYB_MUELLIF.TCKIMLIKNO

Comment: I thought so, DURUM will return as a column, but in the select statement it gives DURUM as invalid identifier

Comment: I found the solution but I can't answer my question

Comment: @Gece: you already have DURUM as part of your select (the alias for the CASE statement). Why do you need to add another column DURUM?

Comment: @Gece: you should either accept CodeBrikie's or my answer, because your final solution is precisely what we were trying to tell you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first occurence of `DURUM` as you do not have a column with that name.

Comment: but I need an extra column like that. How can I put it

Comment: @Gece: you **have** an extra column called DURUM